# Installing an app I created solely for myself

Tags: applications

I was wondering whether I could install an app I create to cater to my personal needs solely for myself? Like a private app!
(I know there are other applications to do this, but I want to learn something in the process)

Comment: Development questions are off-topic, and of course with a question this broad I bet no one can give a complete coverage. Still... _"I was wondering whether I could install this solely for myself?"_ -> yes, through ADB sideloading - in fact it's what happens when you develop and test the app on your device.

Comment: Thank you for both the inputs! I shall remember to be more specific in my questions from next time.

Comment: At first I too thought it was too broad and a development question. But it's actually fine. Just needs an edit. I expect no malicious intent from the asker. Welcome to the site ArgusGallos! Be sure to check the FAQ so you can ask even better questions in the future! :)

Answer (score 3):

So the question can be boiled down to

> Can I install an app I created only on my own device?

Yes you can! If you create the app yourself you are not forced to share it on the Play Store. To actually install the app you will first have to accept apps from unknown sources in your settings. This can generally be found in the security section of the settings.
While the Play Store is the most popular app store on Android (I assume), it has nothing to do with android itself. You can find apps on alternative app stores or even on forum boards or in email attachments.

**If you don't share your app in any way, you will be the only person with that app.**

Of course, once someone gets access to the apk file it becomes trivial to install it on another device.

Comment: Note that you'll have to enable installing apps from unknown sources in the settings in order to install anything that is not on the Play Store.

Comment: Yup, I'll include that in my answer. Thanks for reminding me @Namnodorel !